# Javascript RegEx to Match Against a String

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to identify strings that have the exact templates (can be either of the two):

1. 1 OR 2 Characters (A-Z) and then followed by a number (doesn't matter how many digits).
2. K1E OR K2E and then followed by a number (also doesn't matter how many digits). The letter 'K' and then a '1' OR '2' and then followed by an 'E' is strictly how the string should begin.

This is what I have so far:

```
var word = "K4E43057";
if (word.match(/^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9]/g)
    || word.match(/^[Kk]{1}[12]{1}[Ee]{1}[0-9]/g)) {
    alert("It matches.");
}
```

It's identifying that the string does indeed match, even though the prefix is K4E when it should only be either K1E or K2E. I'm still a little new to regular expressions, so if you could help me out that would be great.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your first regular expression matches: "K4" is a letter followed by a digit. Probably the `{1,2}` in the first regex should just be `{2}`

Comment: Your regex is too broad, if you're only trying to match K1 or K2. Try `/^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[12]/` And are you really OK matching one *or* two letters at the beginning?

Comment: @Pointy Apologies, it is actually one or two letters at the beginning in the first template. Didn't accurately note that. I will make the change now. Thanks!

Comment: @vch It is actually 1 or 2 letters! Should have triple checked that everything was okay before submitting the question.

Comment: @Kellowyn well in that case the word "K4E43057" *should* match, right? It starts with a letter followed by a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `[A-Za-z]`, you can just use the `i` modifier.

You can also collapse the two regular expressions into one with an or clause, `|`.

My revised regular expression:

```
/^([A-Z]{1,2}|K[12]E)\d+$/gi
```

Comment: My mistake. It is actually one OR two letters. Made the revision above.

Answer (score 0):

```
(^[A-Z]{2}\d+$)|(^K[1-2]E\d+$)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a nice tool for you

> http://regex101.com/r/dC2gM3/2.

To match any number of digits you need a `*` at the end.

```
/^[k][12][e][0-9]*/gi
```

I do not know, why the `alternation` with `|` does not work as described by the other answerers on this tool...

Comment: You are welcome. Actually found by @TJCrowder. Big respects!!